# Button not showing inside table BootstrapVue

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to add a button inside the cell "Actions", but the button itself is not showing inside the table

```
<template>
<ContentWrapper>
        <div class="content-heading">Audit Trails</div>
    <div class="my-table" >

    <!-- BOOTSTRAPVUE TABLE -->

    <b-form-input
      v-model="filter"
      type="search"
      placeholder="Search"
    >
    </b-form-input>
    <b-table striped hover style="cursor: pointer" 
    :items="items" 
    :fields="config" 
    :currentPage="currentPage" 
    :perPage="perPage" 
    :filter="filter" 
    @row-clicked="modal" 
    :key="items.name">
      <!-- Adds new cell in table called Actions, inside the cell is the buttons -->
      <template v-slot:cell(actions)>
        <b-button v-b-modal.modal-1>DELETE</b-button>
      </template>
    </b-table>

    <!-- Modal  -->
    <b-modal ref="mymodal" title="BootstrapVue">
      <p class="my-4">Hello from modal!</p>
    </b-modal>
    <b-modal id="modal-1" title="BootstrapVue">
      <p class="my-4">Modal!</p>
    </b-modal>
    <!-- Pagination -->
    <b-pagination
      v-model="currentPage"
      :total-rows="rows"
      :per-page="perPage"
    ></b-pagination>
    
  </div>
</ContentWrapper>
</template>
```

Vue version : 2.6.10
BootstrapVue version : bootstrap-vue@2.0.0-rc.21

Answer (score 1):

This comment in the table isn't accurate

> Adds new cell in table called Actions, inside the cell is the buttons

When using the `fields` prop, you have to pass the field names you use in the template.  Add an `actions` field to the `config` array:

```
config: ['id','name','actions','etc']
```

If you weren't using the `fields` prop, it would be enough to have an `actions` field in your data items.

Either way, the field can't be created by the template.

Comment: Yes I already have actions in config array. But the button is still not showing. Turns out that the bootstrapvue project version im working on is outdated (version 2.0.0). The code works fine on other project with version 2.20.0. Anyways thanks for the help :)!

Comment: I havent tried to update the version yet, but i assume updating it will solve the problem since the code runs well on other project with latest bootstrapvue version.